# matplotlib installation problems on windows

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-analysis

My OS is 64 bit Windows
My Python is 32 bit. I use PyDev in Eclipse

What version of Matplotlib should I install?

For both 32 bit and 64 bit I get problems:

I am just struggling to run this little module.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had similar issues with matplotlib 32-bits on python 2.7 32-bits and Windows 7 64-bits. I remember I needed to manually install a couple of other packages such as dateutil and pyparsing. You might find below link useful.

[Problem With Matplotlib installation](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/2330)

or you can use compiled installers from the link below. You'll need the following dependencies: numpy, dateutil, pytz, pyparsing, six

[Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages
by Christoph Gohlke](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#matplotlib)

Answer (score 1):

These are the downloads you need for Matplotlib to run with Python 2.7 in windows:

numPy:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.9.0/numpy-1.9.0-win32-superpack-python2.7.exe/download

numpy is currently available for Windows only in 32-bit format

Checking your numpy works:

import numpy as np
a = np.arange(10)
a

dateutil and six:
cmd
cd\
cd python27\scripts
pip2.7 install python-dateutil

This should install six as well

pyparsing and pytz:
pip2.7 install pyparsing
pip2.7 install pytz

matplotlib:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/matplotlib/files/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.4.3/windows/matplotlib-1.4.3.win32-py2.7.exe/download?use_mirror=liquidtelecom

Checking to see if your matplotlib finally works:

from matplotlib import pyplot
pyplot.plot([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 4, 9, 16])
pyplot.show()

Hope this helps
Mohammad Saeed

Comment: After posting separate lines have been displayed as a single line. E.g. for installing pyparsing just type pip2.7 install pyparsing. 
Once pyparsing installs then type in the command line editor pip2.7 install pytz

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here and had to fix multiple times. The best solution I found was...

(1) If you don't already have PIP installed, install with instructions on https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html (referenced on python.org site).

(2) Install numpy with unofficial binaries here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy.

(3) Then install matplotlib with PIP via command `pip install matplotlib`
This will install all dependencies correctly (other than `numpy` which required the manual installation).